# How to display only one Commerce product variation in Views?

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I have a view which displays the list of all Commerce Products on the site.

The problem is that it displays variations as separate products.

I've tried:

1. Enabling Views aggregating checkbox
2. Creating a new view which is based on nodes, instead of Commerce Products
3. Checking "Distinct" under "Query options"

However, neither of that worked. I'm not sure if I misconfigured these settings.

I suspect that it has to do something with aggregation/grouping but I can't figure it out for a couple of hours already :@

How can I limit the display of products to only *one* variation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just use this in filter.

Content: Product Reference:delta (= 0)

which will show only one variation of your product.

Comment: brilliant! this will show the first referenced product variation.

Comment: But i am still getting 2 variation of same product.

Comment: This will not work when there are exposed filters because they will use only the 0 delta values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate the product variants with a product display node and then create a view of the product display nodes. If you do this using display suite you then get the option to use display suite in the view (Format: Show: display suite). Doing it this way you don't need to use aggregation.